# Name hiding when multi-inherited

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, name-hiding

According to https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=only-name-hiding, the assignment `x = 0` in the following code is not ambiguous, because the declaration `B::x` has hidden `A::x`.

```
struct A {
   int x;
};

struct B: A {
   int x;
};

struct C: A, B {
   void f() { x = 0; }
};

int main() {
   C i;
   i.f();
}
```

Is this correct? It sounds counterintuitive to me, so I tried copying it to https://cpp.sh/ to compile it. It didn't compile successfully, due to ambiguity.

Comment: It seems to be an error on that ibm page - or the compiler for which the documentation is written is not a pure standard C++ compiler.

Comment: @TedLyngmo fails also here with gcc https://godbolt.org/z/Teed3oEG7

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Yes, it should fail with a C++ compiler. Since the referenced documentation claims that there is no ambiguity, either the documentation is wrong or it is not for a C++ compiler.

Comment: @TedLyngmo oh sorry I misread your comment. "error on that page" is not refering to https://cpp.sh. Ambiguity :P

Comment: I made it clearer :-)

Comment: This is also wrong/misleading "However, the compiler will warn you that deriving C from A is redundant because you already have access to the subobject A through B."

Comment: I'd be surprised if an IBM document with long history of many versions would contain such obvious errors. I am not entirely sure, but from what I read so far I understood that you are looking at the manual of some c++ dialect ("ILE version of c++"). In other words, the article is correct, its just not talking about standard c++

Comment: To make it more (maybe) confusing, if `A` was a **virtual** base of both `B` and `C` the code would be okay, because of the **dominance** rule: in `B`, `x` hides the `A` version, so it also hides it in `C` because `B` dominates `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compiler is right. The article is wrong, supposed it actually describes standard c++ (see pps).

What they say about name hiding applies for example here:

```
struct A {
   int x;
};

struct B: A {
   int x;
   void f() { x = 0; }
};
```

If there were no `int x;` in `B` then `x` in `f()` would refer to `A::x`, but the member is hiding the member of same name from the base, hence `x` in `f` does refer to `B::x`. There is no ambiguity.

This does however, not apply to multiple inheritance as in the example on the page:

> ```
> struct A {
>    int x;
> };
>
> struct B: A {
>    int x;
> };
>
> struct C: A, B {
>    void f() { x = 0; }
> };
> ```

It would actually be weird if the order of `struct C: A,B` vs `struct C: B,A` would determine the namelook up for `x`. Instead, unqualified name lookup for a member in a nutshell works like this:

- the name is found it the class, then look up stops. That the case above in my first example. Otherwise,
- the scope of **all** base classes is considered. If more than one is found there is ambiguity. This is the case in the example from the article. Otherwise,
- ... more steps not relevant here...

This is only a very simple view (just enough to understand the examples), for the details I refer you to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup.

---

PS: THe article has more misleading information.

> However, the compiler will warn you that deriving C from A is redundant because you already have access to the subobject A through B.

"redundant" is the wrong word here. A `C` object has two distinct `A` subobjects. Its just not possible to access either of them, because whatever way you'd use to access it cannot differentiate between the `A` inherited via `B` and the one inherited directly.

---

PPS: The reason for this discrepancy might be that you are looking at (quoted from [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=programming-ile-languages)):

> These manuals provide guidance and reference material for the American National Standards Institute (ANSI) Standard C++ Library and the Integrated Language Environment (ILE) versions of the C and C++ programming languages.

I never heard of a "ILE version of C++" before, though it appears to be a dialect.